# передать значение через $_GET

Tags: php, html

У меня есть выпадающий список моделей машин на странице, при выборе какого-либо элемента из этого списка, название этого элемента должно через $_GET отправляться , а сама страница перезагружаться, для того чтобы в момент перезагрузки подгрузились бы доступные для этой машины услуги

вот сам выпадающий список:

```
<div class="custom-select__dropdown">
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="1">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['7']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="2">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['6']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="3">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['5']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="4">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['4']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="5">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['3']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="6">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['2']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="7">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['1']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-select__item" value="8">
    <?=$arResult['ITEMS']['0']['NAME'] ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Названия элементов подгружаются из битрикса

Comment: у меня ощущение, что этот код красиво выводится вместо select. просто на событие change этого select повесить обработчик.

Comment: форма нужна, чтобы передать значения.